# Kartik Datetime picker yii2

Tags: yii2, kartik-v

I am using Kartik Date picker.
in database I am using timestamp. but checkout value is not set. it shows (not set)

Comment: convert date to timestamp before adding to db.

Comment: taken this : 'format' => 'd-M-Y g:i A', how to convert it?

Answer (score 0):

Before save convert to timestamp

```
$date = date('d-m-Y g:i A');
$dateTimeObject = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y g:i A', $date);
$timestamp = $dateTimeObject->getTimeStamp();
```

When read convert timestamp to datetime

```
$getDate = new \DateTime();
$getDate->setTimestamp($timestamp);
$date = $getDate->format('d-m-Y g:i A');
```